How to remove wrinkles caused by fill
I am making a model for 3D printing
But the bottom surface I filled has produced many wrinkles, which can lead to poor printing results
How can I remove these wrinkles

you can get my file from 
and select the bottom by the vert group "bottom"

You could go into the Data panel > Remesh > Quad > Quadriflow Remesh and try a remesh around 20000 faces? Or try a remesh with the software called Instant Meshes. Then in Sculpt mode use the Smooth brush to smooth this surface?

@moonboots I have already used the retopo plugin, but wrinkles still exist. Smooth brushes are useful, but unfortunately, I would like to create an automated script to implement it, so I will avoid using the sculpt mode feature

Modeling isn't a one-size-fits-all kind of thing. Usually, it's about using different tools and then going in and fixing stuff up manually.

do you mean that you want to create an automated script because you have a lot of these objects?

@moonboots yeah, that's right. so I hope there's a universal way to handle it
